# The symbolic differentiation of univariate expressions

Tags: terminology, functional-programming, mathematical-programming, computer-algebra

I was reading ["Doug McIlroy: McCarthy Presents Lisp"](http://www.paulgraham.com/mcilroy.html) and the phrase "symbolic differentiation of univariate expressions" triggered a faint memory of a demonstration of differentiation done in haskell using higher order functions.  (I think my memory is of using the language to produce a function that is the differential of a function given.)

However I haven't been able to find any other reference to the above phrase in lisp or ML-based languages.

Does anyone have more information on this, and is "symbolic differentiation of univariate expressions" the same thing as the memory I described?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation), which is an entire field of research; many techniques are known.